# joining two queries one containg simple select and one containing a function?

Tags: php, mysql

i have two queries- one containing simple select statement and the other one calls a finction.

example of both are --

```
select xx.a,xx.b,xx.c,aa.d,aa.e,aa.f from xyz_table as xx,abc_table as aa where xx.a=aa.d and xx.id='$id(dynamic id)'
```

other one is--

```
select function_name($id);   // same $id value as above one
```

Now in both the statements $id entered is same.  Now how can i merge these two queries into one single query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  xx.a, xx.b, xx.c, aa.d, aa.e, aa.f, function_name('$id(dynamic id)')
FROM    xyz_table AS xx
JOIN    abc_table AS aa
ON      aa.d = xx.a
WHERE   xx.id = '$id(dynamic id)'
```

Note that the function value will be returned along with each record (and it will be invoked that many times unless it's defined as `DETERMINISTIC`).

Comment: aahh yess....i got a lil confused when i saw these queries :p ....this was so simple! Thanks Quassnoi !!